# Is there a way to customize Notifications in react-admin? also disable if not needed for some resources?

Tags: react-admin

I'm looking to customize the message that's displayed when a new record is created and also disabling the notification on some specific resources.
I can't see any property to manage this with a Create/SimpleForm schema.
Is there a mechanism in place to customize this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize notifications after an action by creating your own actions.
React admin search a `meta` key on the action and triggers some actions from it.

I recommend you to read the whole [Writing Action](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html) documentation, especially the [Handling Side Effect](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#handling-side-effects) part.

Comment: Ok, so it seems there's no out-of-the-box support to customize notifications then, thansk.

Comment: @Kmaschta  HI, I'm using v2.8 . do u have any idea about blocking all notifications(snackbar) ?

Comment: @Shahnad, you can add custom redux middleware and just return null for any SHOW_NOTIFICATIONS